# Inequality Join in Hive and Pig

Tags: sql, join, hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I am starting a project where I need to make some not equality Join.
Now, I've read that neither Pig nor Hive support inequality Join.
I have also read that Pig can support that by using CROSS and FILTER.
Could I do that also in Hive using WHERE clause?Are there any cases where it is not possible?

Finally, supposed that I can do that both in Pig and in Hive, which would be better about performance?

Answer (score 1):

I remember Hive can only use one reducer to do "CROSS". Pig uses a smart approach to implement "CROSS" and run it in parallel and it usually has better performance than Hive.

BTW, I have not updated my knowledge about Hive and Pig for one year. I'm not sure if Hive improved "CROSS" in the past year.